# Returning current month data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Apologies if I'm doing something stupid here
I'm trying to pull stock data from Yahoo Finance (I cannot use Quandl or Iex etc. due to machine restrictions)
For some reason, I can not return stock data unless I'm using a date from the first month of 2018 as my start date. If I use anything else, I receive a KeyError for "Date"

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

tickers = ["WTI","WCS"]

from datetime import datetime
currently = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

testdata = data.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', '2018-01-31', currently)
print(testdata)
```

The given date is just an example; I am not sure if execution of an alternative date outside of that month will produce the same errors for others. I want to retrieve the data only for the current (dynamic) month.

Thanks in advance!